# How to make select list appear over another element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, z-index, reactstrap

I am building a project based on this [React Template](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-kit-react).
In one of the componenets I have a Select List and under it there's a Card element.
The problem is that when I click on the list the items appear under the card element as you see below:

[image]

I had a feeling this was caused by the CSS code of the template itself that configures the card to appear over all other elements.

So what I did is I created a new react project with:

> npx create-react-app

And my suspicion was right.
I copied basically the same code:

```
const selectStyles = {
  control: (styles) => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: "white" }),
  option: (styles) => {
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: "green",
    
      "z-index": -5,
    };
  },
};

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Select
          className="basic-single"
          classNamePrefix="select"
          defaultValue={colourOptions[0]}
          name="color"
          options={colourOptions}
          styles={selectStyles}
        />
        <Card
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            "background-color": "red",
            "z-index": 5,
          }}
        >
          <CardImg
            top
            width="100%"
            src="/assets/318x180.svg"
            alt="Card image cap"
          />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle tag="h5">Card title</CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">
              Card subtitle
            </CardSubtitle>
            <CardText>
              Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
              bulk of the card's content.
            </CardText>
            <Button>Button</Button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And the select items appear **ABOVE** the card:
[image]

The card is colored in red.

**CONCLUSION:** The problem is caused by the card css code of the template.

As you see, I tried with different configurations with the `z-index` attribute, but to no avail.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the z-index and position, whichever content you want to show in the top should have higher z-index value.

- Try giving the select dropdown the high values compared to card.
- Try removing both css attributes position: absolute and z-index if it is not needed. Position absolute is only used when to need to move the content to wherever you want to the respective relative parent container. So if you are just practicing and not doing design try to remove both.